# Arraylist basics

Tags: java, arraylist

> Write a method that recieves an `ArrayList` of integers as a parameter and returns the **index** of the largest integer in the collection.

So far I only have the code needed to receive an `ArrayList` of integers, search for a specific integer and return `true`.

Can anyone tell me what the `int` key is needed for? Wouldn't the code work without it?

```
public static boolean search (ArrayList<Integer>list, int key) {
    for (int=0 ; i< listsize(); i++)
         if (list.get(i) == key) {
            return true;
         } return false;  
    }
```

Comment: The key is what the `search()` method searches for in that `ArrayList`.

Comment: Err, the code sample does not do what the problem asks for...

Comment: Barring the missing `)`, wouldn't this code only check the first index?

Comment: Yes there is missing ) so code looks ok :)

Comment: I fixed the missing ), thanks. But the reason I posted this question was to find out how to do what I stated.

Comment: The signature of the method you've reported is assigned or you invented it?

Comment: Consider the edge case of an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public int getIndexOfMaxValue(final List<Integer> list)
{
    int maxFound = Integer.MIN_VALUE, value;
    int ret = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
        value = list.get(index);
        if (value > maxFound) {
            maxFound = value;
            ret = index;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Note that lists *can* have duplicate elements and that this code will return the index of the *first* maximum found. If you want the last index, just replace `>` with `>=` in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `key` is necessary because the method pictured appears to not be a method to find the max but rather a method to return whether the list *contains* a certain number.

The pictured method does have a logical error because the body of the loop returns immediately if the 0th index is not `key`:

```
if (list.get(i) == key) {
    return true;
}
return false; // <- this should be after the loop
```

Regarding the method that's assigned (I assume it's an assignment):

> Write a method that recieves an ArrayList of integers as a parameter and returns the index of the largest integer in the collection.

No, this method does not need a key variable.

To write a method such as this, the first thing you should do is make sure the list is not empty. An empty list cannot have a max index.

```
if(list.isEmpty()) {
    return -1; // return a special value indicating the list is empty
}
```

That check will also throw a NullPointerException if the list is null. We could check if the list is null and return something else but this is a case where it's probably more informative to throw an exception.

Then you need to keep a variable that is the "current" highest index. We can initialize this to 0 because we already know the list is at least size of 1.

```
int indexOfMax = 0;
```

Then we'll have a loop that compares each index in the list to the current highest index and reassigns it if the number at that index is higher. We can start this loop at 1 because, again, we already know the list's size must at least be 1. The loop will simply break immediately if there are no other indexes. If a list only has one number, then that number is the largest one.

```
for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
```

Then do the comparison and assignment:

```
    if(list.get(i) > list.get(indexOfMax)) {
        indexOfMax = i;
    }
}
```

Finally return our index.

```
return indexOfMax;
```

Answer (score 0):

- First you want to loop the ArrayList starting with i = 2 or 2nd element(assuming you have more than 1 element in the list),
- if you have 1 or less than 1 element in then it simply skips the loop and returns 0 index(frst element). If the element of
- if you have more than 1 element in the list, then it compares the value in the 2nd element to the value element before it, if it is higher or the same,then it sets it as the highestIntIdx.

public static int search(List list) {

```
    int highestIntIdx= 0;

    for (int i = 1;i<list.size();i++){

        if(list.isEmpty())
            break;

        if (list.get(i) >= list.get(i-1)){
            highestIntIdx = i;
        }
    }
    return highestIntIdx;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You appear to have been asked to return the index of the largest integer in the ArrayList.

So you will want to implement a method liek

```
package com.snippet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Largest {

public Largest() {
}

public int getIndexOfLargest(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int index;

    if (list == null) {
        index = -1;
    } else {
        index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) > list.get(index)) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

}